# delayed_job :run_at is not working. all jobs set to run at current time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have installed the collectiveidea fork for delayed_job at

git://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.git

but cannot get it to accept **:run_at**

from my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

when I try it in the console

```
1.9.2-p318 :005 > Time.now
=> 2012-03-24 10:20:34 -0700 
1.9.2-p318 :006 > User.delay.new :run_at => 5.days.from_now
 SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs` (`attempts`, `created_at`, `failed_at`, `handler`, `last_error`, `locked_at`, `locked_by`, `priority`, `run_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["attempts", 0], ["created_at", Sat, 24 Mar 2012 17:20:36 UTC +00:00], ["failed_at", nil], ["handler", "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/class 'User'\nmethod_name: :new\nargs:\n- :run_at: 2012-03-29 17:20:36.876374000Z\n"], ["last_error", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["locked_by", nil], ["priority", 0], ["run_at", Sat, 24 Mar 2012 17:20:36 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 24 Mar 2012 17:20:36 UTC +00:00]]
 (2.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job id: 17, priority: 0, attempts: 0, handler: "--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject:...", last_error: nil, run_at: "2012-03-24 17:20:36", locked_at: nil, failed_at: nil, locked_by: nil, created_at: "2012-03-24 17:20:36", updated_at: "2012-03-24 17:20:36">
```

I see there is some UTC offset in the runtime, but based on Time.now, I can tell run_at is not going forward by 5 days.

"run_at", Sat, 24 Mar 2012 17:20:36 UTC +00:00

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14):

You made a mistake passing :run_at as parameter to initialize method of User model.

Try:

```
User.delay(:run_at => 5.days.from_now).new
```